# Independent vs dependment events and their intersection

Tags: probability

[image]

Above excerpt is from [John A Rice's Book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/8131519546). What I can't understand is how $P(A \cap B \cap C) = 0$

By associative law:  $P(A\cap B\cap C) = P(A \cap B) \cap C$

Also:

1. $P(H_1) = P(H_2) = \frac {1}{2} = $ getting a head
2. $P(C) = \frac {1}{2} = $ getting a head
3. $P(H_1 \cap H_2) = $ getting a head

Hence, 
$P(A \cap B) \cap C = P(H_1 \cap H_2) \cap P(C) = Head \bigcap Head = Head = \frac 12$

Comment: Sidenote on notation, what exactly do you mean by $P(A \cap B) \cap C$? It does't make much sense to have "common set of probability distribution and random variable".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$A$ says that first should be Head. $B$ says that second should be head. So, $A\cap B$ basically says the set of possible outcomes is $\{HH\}$. But, $C$ says that *exactly* one toss should be head, i.e. $\{HT,TH\}$. Their intersection is empty set, so the probability is $0$.

In your post, $(∩)∩$ doesn't make sense because the first term is a probability, not a set.

Comment: Looks like I confused set theory with probability theory. It means, set theory laws don't directly map to probability theory laws.

Also, ${HH}$ is same as ${H, H}$. I mean, a comma was needed to make sure the coin was tossed twice, hence two events

Comment: They apply, otherwise mathematics wouldn't exist. It's just you can't take intersection of a real number and a set. $P(A\cap B)$ is a real number such as $1/4$ and $C$ is an event set, and $1/4\cap \{HT,TH\}$ doesn't make sense.